# Doubt in multivariate Taylor's theorem

Tags: taylor-expansion

The way [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor%27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) presents it, I don't understand how many functions $h_\alpha$ do we have in the remainder term?

Using matrix notation, $$f({\boldsymbol {x}})=f({\boldsymbol {a}})+\nabla f(\boldsymbol a)^\top({\boldsymbol {x}}-{\boldsymbol {a}})+h({\boldsymbol {x}})\lVert {\boldsymbol {x}}-{\boldsymbol {a}}\rVert ,\qquad \lim _{{\boldsymbol {x}}\to {\boldsymbol {a}}}h({\boldsymbol {x}})=0.$$
is the expression we get for Taylor's theorem for linear term. Can we say something analogous about quadratic term in terms of Hessian?

In other words, can someone tell me how to write the remainder of multivariable Taylor's theorem in matrix notation for two terms (i.e. when the function is assumed to be twice differentiable at the point)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you have
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x + h) &= f(x) + f'(x) \cdot h + \ldots + \dfrac{1}{(p-1)!} f^{(p-1)}(x) \cdot h^{(p-1)} \\
&+ \int\limits_0^1 dt\ \dfrac{(1-t)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!} f^{(p)}(x+th) \cdot h^{(p)},
\end{align*}
$$
where the integral is well defined,
$$
\int\limits_0^1 dt\ \dfrac{(1-t)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!} \Big(f^{(p)}(x+th) \cdot h^{(p)}\Big) = \left( \int\limits_0^1 dt\  \dfrac{(1-t)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!} f^{(p)}(x+th) \right) \cdot h^{(p)}
$$

Where $f^{(k)}$ is the $k$th derivative of $f$ (which is a $k$-linear function) and $h^{(k)} = (h, \ldots, h) = h \otimes \mathbf{1}_k$ (and $h \in \mathbf{R}^d,$ assuming $f:\mathbf{R}^d \to \mathbf{R}^c$).

See, (8.14.3) of Foundations of Modern Analysis by Jean Dieudonné. Note that when $p = 2,$ $f^{(2)}(x)$ is a symmetric bilinear function whose matrix representation is the Hessian, in other words, $f^{(2)}(x) \cdot (h_1, h_2) = h_1^\intercal \mathbf{H}_f(x) h_2,$ where $\mathbf{H}_f(x)$ is the Hessian of $f$ at $x.$

**Ammend.** The previous formula assumes $f$ to be $p$ times differentiable with continuity in a ball centred at $x.$ If we only assume $f$ to be $p$ times differentiable at $x$ (so that $f$ is $p-1$ times differentiable in a ball around $x$ and thr $(p-1)$th derivative is assumed differentiable at $x$), we obtain the weaker form of the previous result:
$$
\|f(x+h) - T_f^p(x; h)\| = o(\|h\|^p),
$$
where $T_f^p(x; h)$ is the Taylor polynomial of $f$ of degree (at most) $p$ evaluated at $h,$ namely
$$
T_f^p(x; h) = f(x) + f'(x) \cdot h + \ldots + \dfrac{1}{p!} f^{(p)}(x) \cdot h^{(p)}.
$$
The proof of this second result is given in Cartan's *Differential Calculus* (unfortunately out of print for decades now), Theorem 5.6.3.

Comment: Seemingly you're assuming differentiability of $f$ at a ball around $x$, while I am assuming $f$ to be twice differentiable only at $x$.

Comment: Can we say something like theorem 5 [here](https://eml.berkeley.edu/~anderson/Econ204/TaylorsTheoremTimeless.pdf) for function which is twice differentiable only at the point, not in an interval?

Comment: In that case, the Taylor polynomial goes to degree $p$ and you have to replace the integral with a $o(\|h\|^p)$ term. See Dieudonné's book (he is the ultimate reference on Calculus in Banach spaces).

Comment: Both proofs are rather short and I'd add them here but it is much more fruitful if you read Dieudonné's original treatment of Calculus in Banach Spaces (chapter 8 of his book, about 60 pages) or read Cartan's knock-off (as admitted by himself) of Dieudonné's work, which is a book of about 100 pages (same content though, just more explanation).

Comment: Thank you William!